# C# Find file foreach folder

Tags: c#

Basically I try to open a file foreach folder in a specify path.
For example -
In a specify path i have a folder named "A", inside this folder there is another folders named "B1" "B2" "B3" and so, and inside those folders there is another folder called "C" foreach "C" folder there is a file named "D".
I am trying to take the "B" folders into a combo box and when selecting a folder to open the "D" file.

```
A > B1 > C > D.txt
  > B2 > C > D.txt
  > B3 > C > D.txt
```

and so on.
Please help me manage this.

```
var tfs =
TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(path));
var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
     private void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        var tfs =
            TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs2012:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection_2010/"));
        var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        var workspace = vcs.QueryWorkspaces(workspaceName, vcs.AuthorizedUser, Environment.MachineName)[0];
        _workspace = workspace;
        tvWksNavigator.Nodes.Clear();
            var info = new DirectoryInfo(workspace.Folders[10].LocalItem);
            if (info.Exists)
            {
                var rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name) { Tag = info };
                TreeNode bNode;
                DirectoryInfo[] subSubDirs;
                foreach (var subDir in info.GetDirectories().Where(c => c.Name=="Media"))
                {
                    bNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
                    bNode.Tag = subDir;
                    subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();

                    if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
                    {
                        GetDirectories(subSubDirs, bNode);
                    }
                    rootNode.Nodes.Add(bNode);            
                }
                tvWksNavigator.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
            }
    }

    private void GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo[] subDirs,
        TreeNode nodeToAddTo)
    {
        TreeNode aNode;
        DirectoryInfo[] subSubDirs;
        foreach (var subDir in subDirs)
        {
            aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
            aNode.Tag = subDir;
            aNode.ImageKey = "folder";
            subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();

            if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
            {
                GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
            }
            nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I made a tree view, but I could not take the specific place of each folder

Comment: Yes please show what you have so far.  Also do you always know the folder structure?  Will there ever be a B4?  Can the tree extend to directories beyond C?

Comment: That will be always the folders structure, and yes the tree can extend to directories beyond "C", it will always be named "C".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that can get you going. First off, fill the ComboBox with the folders within folder `A`:

```
private void FillComboBox()
{
    foreach(string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Temp\A"))
    {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        //foldersCB is the Name of the ComboBox
        foldersCB.Items.Add(info);
    }
}
```

The you need an event for when another folder is selected from the ComboBox, we'll use the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
private void foldersCB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = foldersCB.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string filePath = GetFileFromFolder(selectedItem);
    //open the file using 'filePath'
}
```

And `GetFileFromFolder()` is a method which will simply get the first filename matching a path that ends with `D.txt`:

```
private string GetFileFromFolder(string path)
{
    string fileName = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*D.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();
    return fileName;
}
```

Please note that this is just an example to get you going and not a complete solution! For example, if you need to check if the file is really in the subfolder of the selected folder, you'll need to build in extra validation yourself. Hope this helps.